# mod_auth_openidc build steps on windows 64bit

Tags: apache2.4, mod-auth-openidc

I am trying to compile mod_auth_openidc module on windows 7 64bit os
I got source code from 
[Source Code from github](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/releases)

I tried to build this module using visual studio 2015 but it was throwing an error "You must use GNU compiler".
From last few days am trying to build this in windows but ...

Could you please help me to build this module in windows or if any one done this in windows can you please share build steps.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to download the binary that is compiled for Windows from the release page but if you insist you can follow the guidelines from: http://wgsnetman.blogspot.nl/2013/04/building-apache-244-from-unix-source.html with a lot of adaptations/workarounds...

Comment: I tried this but mod_auth_openidc module is not present in apache24 source code. I think this is third party module

Answer (score 0):

The code for mod_auth_openidc was forked to this git repository https://github.com/dematic-spe/mod_auth_openidc.
The build steps as documented on that page are:
bootstrap-windows.cmd
build.cmd - the output is in the tartet folder. The output is two zip files, one for x86 and one for x64.
deploy_to_artifactory.cmd
There were a couple of minor edits to the code so that it would also compile for win32 as well.  It used the microsoft vcpkg project which is great at compiling a lot of opensource code for windows.  I tested it all with VC2019.